# Animate count variable with javascript post update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a variable that is updated with ajax polling a script and pulling the resulting post data every 10 seconds - javascript then updates the div id as demonstrated below:

```
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $example_url ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data) {
                jQuery("#example_data").html(data.example_data);

            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,10000);
</script>

  <p id="example_data"><?php echo $example_data ?></p>
```

What I'd love to do is actually count up from the last number displayed to the updated post value using a javascript animation every time this number updates (every 10 seconds). I'm currently able to get both the value prior to the last 10 seconds and the value after as post variables. I'm also able to count up to a static number from another number using the code below - but I don't know how to set this up to so that the post values trigger the below animation (take from [here](https://codepen.io/hi-im-si/pen/uhxFn), can anyone help me count up every 10 seconds with posted variables?

```
<?php

echo '
<div class="counter" data-count='.$example_data.'>'.$example_data_less_10_seconds.'</div>
'
?>

<script>

$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },

  {

    duration: 20000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }

  });  

});

</script>
```

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://codepen.io/shivasurya/pen/FatiB)?

Comment: pretty sure i already have that with the count function included in my question. My real question is how to i update this to run every 10 seconds with new variables?

Comment: Not clear though, I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/bfbanc4k/) here. Please check and give your feedback.

Comment: What's not clear, let me know and I can try and fix it? Also there is no output in your fiddle?

Comment: Updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/bfbanc4k/1/), check now.

Comment: Great, thanks for this I can definitely build on this to input my variables, thanks!

Comment: Should i add this as an answer, so that you can accept it as correct answer?

Comment: I'll post the answer when I've built in the variables and attribute credit to you

Comment: ok, let me know if further help required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mrid/ju4f0ezq/3/)

Try using this

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function refresh_div() {
    var prev_count = parseInt(jQuery("#example_data").text());
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $example_url ?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data) {
            var new_count = data.example_data;

            $({count: prev_count}).animate({count: new_count}, {
                duration: 600,
                easing: 'linear',
                progress: function() { 
                    $('#example_data').text(numberWithCommas(Math.ceil(this.count*100)/100));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

t = setInterval(refresh_div,10000);
```

Comment: This is great however, if the target number is lower than the start (i.e. a decrease is required) then the finished variable always = target + 1 - try setting new_count in your fiddle as 10 - you'll see that the end value after decrease is 11, is there anyway to stop this to the end number on decrease = the target?

Comment: @user1419810 i have updated my answer and the fiddle

Comment: One last question, is there any way to output the results to 2 decimal places with a thousand separator?